# javascript and json

Tags: javascript, json, struts2

I'm using javascript with a json library and running into a little trouble.  Here's my json output:

```
{
    "artist": {
        "username": "myname",
        "password": "password",
        "portfolioName": "My Portfolio",
        "birthday": "2010-07-12 17:24:36.104 EDT",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Smith",
        "receiveJunkMail": true,
        "portfolios": [{
            "entry": [{
                "string": "Photos",
                "utils.Portfolio": {
                    "name": "Photos",
                    "pics": [""]
                }
            },
            {
                "string": "Paintings",
                "utils.Portfolio": {
                    "name": "Paintings",
                    "pics": [""]
                }
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

In javascript I'm trying to access the entries in the map like so:

```
var portfolios = jsonObject.artist.portfolios.entry;
var portfolioCount = portfolios.length;

for ( var index = 0;  index < portfolioCount; index++ ) 
{
   var portfolio = portfolios[index];
   txt=document.createTextNode("Portfolio Name: " + portfolio['string']  );
   div = document.createElement("p");
   div.appendChild ( txt );
   console.appendChild(div);
}
```

but portfolios is "undefined".  What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that it's portfolios that's undefined and not portfolios.entry?

Comment: It may not be the source of your issue, but your JSON isn't valid.  The line should be `"receiveJunkMail": "true",`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your JSON results. `portfolios` is a one-element array; `portfolios[0]` is an object containing a single key, `entry`, which maps to an array of two objects that have both `string` and `utils.Portfolio` keys. Thus, the syntax `jsonObject.artist.portfolios.entry` will not work. Instead, you want `jsonObject.artist.portfolios[0].entry`.

If possible, I would suggest changing whatever code generates those JSON results to remove the `entry` level of indirection entirely, e.g. like so:

```
{
  "artist": {
    /* ... */
    "portfolios": [
      {
        "string": "Photos",
        "utils.Portfolio": {
            "name": "Photos",
            "pics": [""]
        }
      },
      {
          "string": "Paintings",
          "utils.Portfolio": {
              "name": "Paintings",
              "pics": [""]
          }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then you could access it with

```
var portfolios = jsonObject.artist.portfolios;
for (var i = 0, portfolio; portfolio = portfolios[i]; ++i)
{
    // use portfolio variable here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an array in your object.  I believe you're looking for this:

```
var portfolios = jsonObject.artist.portfolios[0].entry;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `portfolios` property is an array, so you need to use an index to get the first element:

```
var portfolios = jsonObject.artist.portfolios[0].entry;
```